# How to evaluate a web service framework

Tags: web, service, frameworks, servicestack, nancy

I am trying to **evaluate different web service frameworks** for API development in .Net.  So far the frameworks I've been looking at are:

- ServiceStack
- MVC
- Web API
- NancyFx

I'm trying to find some common talking-points between the frameworks so I know what to look for when picking a framework.  The talking points I've got so far are:

- The Framework beliefs and principles
- The Architecture of the framework (Client and Service side)
- The Stack the framework provides you with
- The Ease of development within the stack (plugins etc)
- End-to-end performance benchmarks
- Scalability benchmarks
- Framework documentation availability
- Framework Support (Cross platform etc)
- Pricing
- Overall Conclusion

**Can anyone think of anything else I should think about?**  By the end of the research I'm hoping to write about each framework in detail and to make comparisons as to which framework to chose for a given purpose.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**End to End Productivity** - The core essence for a Service is to *provide a Service* that ultimately delivers some value to its consumers. Therefore the end-to-end productivity of consuming services should also be strongly considered as the ease of which Services can be consumed from clients and least effort to consume them, ultimately provides more value to clients which is often more valuable than the productivity of developing Services themselves since the value is multiplied across its multiple consumers. As many services constantly evolve, the development workflow of updating Services and how easy it is to determine what's changed (i.e. if they have a static API) also impacts productivity on the client.

**Interoperability** - Another goal of a Service is interoperability and how well Services can be consumed from heterogeneous environments, most Web Service Frameworks just do HTTP however in many cases in Intranet environments sending API requests via a MQ is more appropriate as it provides greater resilience than HTTP, time-decoupling, natural load-balancing, decoupled endpoints, improved messaging workflows and error recovery, etc. There are also many Enterprises (and Enterprise products) that still only support or mandate SOAP so having SOAP endpoints and supporting XSD/WSDL metadata can also be valuable.

**Versionability** - Some API designs are naturally better suited to versioning where evolving Services can be enhanced defensively without breaking existing Service Consumers.

**Testability and Mockability** - You'll also want to compare the ease of which Services can be tested and mocked to determine how easy it is to create integration tests and whether it requires new knowledge and infrastructure as well as how easy it supports parallel client development which is important when front and backend teams develop solutions in parallel where the API contracts of a Service can be designed and agreed upon prior to development to ensure it meets the necessary requirements before implementation, then the front and backend teams can implement them independently of each other. If the Services haven't been implemented the clients would need to "mock" the Service responses until they have, then later switch to use the real services once they've been implemented.

**Learnability** how intuitive it is to develop Services, the amount of cognitive and conceptual overhead required also affects productivity and the ability to reason about how a Service Framework works and what it does has an impact on your Solutions overall complexity and your teams ability to make informed implementation decisions that affect performance and scalability and the effort it takes to ramp up new developers to learn your solution.